# ¿Por qué genera mal el resultado del bucle en C?

Tags: c

La situación es la siguiente: tengo este pequeño programa en C, en donde el usuario ingresa una cadena de 6 caracteres.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char cadena[7], cadena2[7];
    int i;
    printf("Ingrese una cadena de 6 simbolos: ");
    scanf(" %s", cadena);
    while((strlen(cadena)) != 6)
        {
            printf("\nLa cadena %s no es de 6 simbolos. Por favor ingrese una nueva: ", cadena);
            scanf(" %s", cadena);
        };
    printf("\nPREFIJOS:\n");
    for(i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                {
                    printf("%c\n", 155);
                }
            else
                {
                    strncpy(cadena2, cadena, i);
                    printf("%d %s\n", i, cadena2);
                };
        };
}
```

Mi objetivo es lograr que se muestren todos los prefijos de esa cadena, es decir, si ingreso la cadena 'abcabc' el programa deberia mostrar: 'abcabc' 'abcab' 'abca' 'abc' 'ab' 'a' '', pero el sistema me devuelve lo siguiente:

- 6 abcabc
- 5 abcabc
- 4 abcabc
- 3 abcabc
- 2 abcabc
- 1 abcabc
- ø

No logro encontrar donde está el problema. ¿La función strncpy() esta bien utilizada en este caso?

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en que cuando copias por primera vez la cadena esta se mantiene siempre de la misma manera porque no se borran los caracteres anteriores por lo tanto tienes que limpiar la posición o hacerlo de manera ascendente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
void main()
{
    char cadena[7] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    char cadena2[7] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int i;
    printf("Ingrese una cadena de 6 simbolos: ");
    scanf(" %s", cadena);
    while ((strlen(cadena)) != 6)
    {
        printf("\nLa cadena %s no es de 6 simbolos. Por favor ingrese una nueva: ", cadena);
        scanf(" %s", cadena);
    };
    printf("\nPREFIJOS:\n");
    for (i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("%c\n", 155);
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(cadena2, cadena, i);
            if (i != 6) {
                cadena2[i + 1] = ' ';
            }
            printf("%d %s\n", i, cadena2);
        };
    };
}
```

Esta manera más eficiente sería así

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
void main()
{
    char cadena[7] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    char cadena2[7] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int i;
    printf("Ingrese una cadena de 6 simbolos: ");
    scanf(" %s", cadena);
    while ((strlen(cadena)) != 6)
    {
        printf("\nLa cadena %s no es de 6 simbolos. Por favor ingrese una nueva: ", cadena);
        scanf(" %s", cadena);
    };
    strncpy(cadena2, cadena, 6);
    printf("\nPREFIJOS:\n");
    for (i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("%c\n", 155);
        }
        else
        {
            
            if (i != 6) {
                cadena2[i + 1] = ' ';
            }
            printf("%d %s\n", i, cadena2);
        };
    };
}
```

En orden ascendente sería así

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
void main()
{
    char cadena[7] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    char cadena2[7] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int i;
    printf("Ingrese una cadena de 6 simbolos: ");
    scanf(" %s", cadena);
    while ((strlen(cadena)) != 6)
    {
        printf("\nLa cadena %s no es de 6 simbolos. Por favor ingrese una nueva: ", cadena);
        scanf(" %s", cadena);
    };
    printf("\nPREFIJOS:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("%c\n", 155);
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(cadena2, cadena, i);
            printf("%d %s\n", i, cadena2);
        };
    };
}
```